# How do I plot normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, mathematica

If I know the range (1-24) and know the area (X), how can I plot a normal distribution so that the curve has area X?

Comment: A normal distribution does not have a particular range. It stretches, in principle, all the way from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. What you need to know instead of a range is the _mean_ and _standard deviation_ of the distribution.

Comment: A normal distribution has area 1

Comment: So the question is, what _is_ it that you're trying to plot? "Why" might also be useful to know.

Comment: What is the variance? I think you are saying the mean is 11.5 from you range.

Comment: ah, sorry, I misunderstood the definition of normal distribution. I just wanted to get a plot of a bell curve, but now that I think about it, without any more data there can be infinite number of potential curves..

Comment: never mind, I'm just trying to make sense of some data I have, gonna have to take another approach.

Comment: What will you use to plot with? Mathematica, Matlab, Python, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would plot a normal distribution in Matlab for different $i = \mu$ and $j = \sigma$.

```
x = linspace(-10, 10, 5000);

for i = 0:1:5
    for j = 1:1:6
        n = 1/(j^2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(x - i)^2/(2*j^2));
        hold on
        plot(x,n)
    end
end
```

So I plotted $\mu = 0, 1, \ldots, 5$ against $\sigma = 1,2,\ldots, 6$. If you want to plot just $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$, then you would do

```
x = linspace(-5, 5, 5000);

n = 1/(1^2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(x - 0)^2/(2*1^2));
plot(x, n)
```

[image]

---

In Mathematica (this is slow), but you can do

```
Show[Table[
  Plot[1/(j^2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) Exp[-(x - i)^2/(2 j^2)], {x, -10, 15}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 15}, {0, 0.4}}, AspectRatio -> 1,ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], {x, -10, 
   15}, {i, 0, 5}, {j, 1, 6}]]
```

and for just one instance

```
Plot[1/(1^2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) Exp[-(x - 0)^2/(2 1^2)], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]